# Ansible -m Setup filter option not working for Windows hosts?

Tags: ansible

This command works on localhost (Ubuntu):

```
ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_*_mb'
```

When I try run this againts my Windows group, the filtering doesnt seem to work, as I always receive the full output. Is this a known limitation?

Comment: maybe your hosts structure. can you try to use a differently tailored hosts.ini ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `filter` in setup module is not supported for Windows targets.

Referring to the [Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html#notes) of setup module,

> If the target host is Windows, you will not currently have the ability
>   to use filter as this is provided by a simpler implementation of the
>   module.

Comment: so there is a 'simpler implementaion' according the docs, but I can't find it.

Comment: No. The`simpler` here refers to the mimic of shell type filtering which can only work in *nix based targets. No fancy implementation is available.